# Lock Screen image gets changed by itself (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

Lock Screen image gets changed to an album cover of a song (The Shins- New Slang). 
I have no idea why. I have to change it back every time.
How do I stop this?

Edit: I got it. Delete contents in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\\ReadOnly

To find your SID number, open CMD and run the following command – whoami/user.

Comment: Maybe you enabled some setting to use local images?

Comment: What do you have in *Settings > Personalization > Lock screen*?

Comment: There are three options on lock screen background settings: Windows Spotlight, Picture, Slide Show. Currently, I have set it to Picture.

Comment: So it's expected. It'll pick the background from your local files.

Comment: Does this also happen after you login? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc When I boot the system, the lock screen(login) page comes up and the background image is an album cover of a song on E drive. After I login the desktop (home?) comes up and there's no problem here, the wallpaper is the same I had set. When I open _Settings_ > _Personalization > _Lock screen_  it shows the album cover as the lock screen image. If I were to change it now and lock the system, it gets changed. When I restart it, it's set back to the album cover.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Yes it should pick from the local files, but it should show the image I selected. The image currently being shown is an album cover embedded in a .mp3 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are reports about the latest Windows 10 version overriding the lock-screen
setting on startup, with the situation returning to normal after the user login.

It seems like you are a victim of that Windows bug. As this is a bug, there
is no solution, except waiting for a correction by Microsoft.

In the meantime, you could add your voice by reporting the bug to Microsoft
using the Feedback Hub.

Comment: Yes. I just solved it manually. 



Artist covers are stored at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.ZuneMusic_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\ImageCache\20


Cached images of lock screen are stored at 
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\S-1-5-21-491257733-1718714546-2214601280-1001\ReadOnly

Somehow a file from the former directory is being copied into the subfolders of the latter one. I had to delete them manually by changing folder ownership.

Comment: That gives more information to be included in the feedback report.